# Why should the fullwave current sensor bandwith be about 10 times switching frequency?

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, boost, current-sensing

This is an example of high side switch current sensor in a buck-boost converter. 
I read that for high-side switch full waveform sensing the current sensor bandwith should be about 10 times switching frequency. 
Can anyone explain where the number comes from?

[image]

(from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0026269217304743)

Comment: Think about the shape of the current, and its content in terms of harmonics. To have the full waveform at the output, the sensing amplifier should not filter out the "important" contents.

Comment: _"Can anyone explain where the number comes from?"_ - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/why-have-we-chosen-our-number-system-to-be-decimal-base-10

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth limit of f -3dB for half power means the phase = 6 deg at f/10 .  This reduces your phase margin and this may be a minimum compromise in a feedback loop.

Comment: actually it's ten times higher than switching frequency instead.

Comment: That’s the same thing. The sensor is the f-3db and the switch rate is f/10

Comment: if so then why not two, three times to reduce the phase shift further?

Comment: That is an option. 10x should be suggested as a minimum. It’s a tradeoff between SNR and phase shift.

Comment: Can you explain why its minimum?

Comment: No I cannot compute the optimal BW or minimum

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different currents to measure. In current-mode converters it is the switch current that is important-you measure what's going on during a single cycle and switch accordingly.

The current in the switch is 0 at the beginning of the cycle, then it quickly goes to where the inductor current is, then slowly rises until the controller switches off and goes back to zero. So you need the bandwidth to accurately sense the threshold before switching off.

The other current to be measured is the output current, which is equal to the average inductor current, and there you normally don't need anything more than 1/10 of the switching frequency.

*why do you even use a current mode converter? Well, it can protect you from a short circuit, and generally provides more adequate behaviour with less transients on power up.

A voltage mode converter simply measures the output voltage (Vfb and the resistors) and adjusts the switching duty cycle to reach the reference voltage on Vfb. Adjusting voltage may mean relatively high currents. So instead with the current mode converter the output current is adjusted (well, actually the peak switch current) until the voltage reaches the reference. So the current is never too high. A bonus-if you have a short circuit, it is detected on the switch, and the converter is turned off.

Comment: Are you talking about peak current mode control? The one above is to sense the full waveform instead of peak only.

Comment: Then I am not sure what is the question. Of course you need at least ten times higher bandwidth to see what's inside that window

Comment: I asked why the current sense bandwidth should be about 10 times switching frequency? 
(for full waveform current sensing)

Comment: Why 10 and not 100? Or why 10 and not 2?

Comment: That is what I'm asking.

Comment: Which one :) it's at least 10 because otherwise everything interesting is filtered out (just have a look at what the waveform should be) and it's not 100 because it's simply too hard to do it.

Comment: I know that but I want something more authentic than that.

Comment: Why 10, why not 2 as nyquist sampling theorem? Where the number 10 comes from?

Comment: @anhnha What is the waveform of the sensed current? Is it a sine wave? If yes, then sampling a sine wave with higher than 2 samples per period might work. If it is not a sine wave, there are frequency harmonics higher than the fundamental. A square wave has infinite bandwidth in theory, and with bandwidth limited to only 10x times the fundamental switching frequency barely looks like a square wave.

Comment: @Justme it's a triagle waveform like this.
https://www.powersystemsdesign.com/power-inductors-and-peak-current-handling-capability/22

Comment: It's not like that

Comment: @GregoryKornblum what is not like that?

Comment: the waveform is not like that. not the first image at least. if you are looking on the triangle wave- it's the inductor current, not the switch current